# how to capture different modes of refresh event in a web page other that F5 key press?

Tags: refresh

i am developing an MVC application in which i need to capture the different modes of web page refresh event.

---

1. F5 key press
2. view >> Refresh
3. Mouse Right Click >> Refresh
4. Refresh button click beside the address bar (for IE 7).
5. Ctrl + R

---

i need to set a variable to false when the page is refreshed by the above following ways. i tried it via **window.onbeforeunload** event, but it also gets triggered when the web page is closed wherein i need to do some other operation.
i was able to capture F5 key press via e.keyCode == 116 , but not able to capture others.
is there any common way to capture all such refreshes?